# 20A Split Receptacles Using Tandem Breakers

Tags: electrical, receptacle, circuit-breaker

I am planning on putting two 20A split receptacles in my shop, each powered by a 20A-20A tandem breaker. Can I have a split receptacle connected to one tandem breaker? Or does one one plug from each receptacle have to be connected to different tandem breakers?

Comment: So long as you use **2 neutrals** as well as 2 hots, the wiring would be OK... but that does **not** solve common shutoff for two items on one yoke, and I don't know if tandem handle-ties are a thing that's made.

Answer (score 13):

There are two ways to do this, and a *big* possible complication:

- Simple Tandem (a.k.a. Double-Stuff) Breakers

With a simple tandem, the two breakers are independent - each has its own hot and neutral, and in a typical *cable* (as opposed to conduit) setup, each hot/neutral is in a separate cable. Remove the tabs from *both* sides of the receptacle, and connect one hot/neutral to the top and the other to the bottom.

Keep in mind that if you turn off *one* of the breakers or one of them trips, the other will still be hot. That is a safety concern when working on the receptacle. For example, if a tool plugged into the top overloads and trips a breaker, the bottom will still have power. Which means that if you think it is a *receptacle* problem and you take the faceplate off, you will now be dealing with a hot receptacle even though you *know* the breaker just tripped. There *is* a requirement for common shutoff - i.e., if you manually turn off one breaker then you turn off the other as well, enforced by a *handle tie*. There definitely is *not* a requirement for common trip. So be careful!

- Multi-Wire Branch Circuit (MWBC)

An MWBC is one circuit with two hots and one neutral. It can provide two separate (but linked) 120V receptacles (or groups of receptacles) and/or 240V receptacles. The typical use is in a kitchen to power top/bottom receptacles (like you described) with a single 3-wire (plus ground) cable. You can do that here as well. The catch is that an MWBC doesn't use a simple tandem. It uses two breakers that are next to each other but on different legs of the circuit. You will know if you got it right because the two hot wires will have 240V between them - if the two hots have 0V then they are on the same leg and that is *not* allowed for an MWBC because it can lead to an overloaded neutral.

A standard tandem is on one leg. There are some *quad* breakers for some panels which have an outer pair and an inner pair. A quad breaker spans two spaces (so two legs) but has 4 breakers (equivalent of two tandems). If designed to do so, the outer pair and the inner pair can each be a *double breaker* instead of two single breakers, so that each pair can then be used for a 240V circuit (e.g., dryer, water heater) or an MWBC.

An MWBC *must* have common shutoff because of the neutral wire concerns if only one breaker in the pair is turned off. An MWBC does not require common trip, but the easiest way to get common shutoff is to use a double breaker, which also provides common trip.

##### GFCI

There is a big problem with this plan. Typical "shop" areas (garage, unfinished basement, etc.) now require GFCI protection. GFCI can be done a few ways, the main ones being:

- Breaker

The problem is that GFCI breakers are not generally (as far as I know, not at all) available as tandem or quad breakers. They *are* available now as double *full size* breakers, so if the goal is to get the split receptacles but not to save panel space, then that's OK. If the goal is to save panel space then this simply won't work.

- Receptacle

Receptacles with GFCI can't be split. Which means you have a single hot and neutral powering *both* receptacles. The solution is to use a pair of GFCI/receptacles, one powered from each breaker. If you are using an MWBC, you split the neutral (pigtail) before the GFCI/receptacles (inside the junction box). This does require some understanding about usage - i.e., that each duplex receptacle gets 20A, so the split is between duplex GFCI/receptacles and not between top and bottom but will work just fine - all you need is a big enough box.

Comment: Assuming the desire to split the outlets is just for a more compact/elegant installation, it seems worth abandoning that to overcome the problems noted here, and using the last solution offered: two GFCIs in a two-gang box.

Answer (score 7):

Relevant Code:

> **210.7 Multiple Branch Circuits**.
>
> Where two or more branch circuits supply devices or equipment on the same yoke, a means to simultaneously disconnect the ungrounded conductors supplying those devices shall be provided at the point at which the branch circuits originate.

### Can't do it, sorry.

The problem isn't phasing - you can solve that with separate neutral wires.

The problem is, **2 circuits going to the same yoke *must be handle-tied*** with an approved handle-tie.  And there is no way to put a handle-tie on a tandem.  On purpose. Because in 98% of the applications for a handle tie, that would be bad/dangerous.  Welcome to the 2%.

However, you can use a quadplex breaker (aka a tandem tandem that supports 240V circuits - one on the inner breakers, and one some quads, one on the outer breakers as well.   This application does not require "common trip".

This will almost certainly force you to put the two independent circuits on opposite poles. Given that problem, why not consider a MWBC?

### Wiring as a MWBC will also allow 240V support

Normally an application like this is wired as a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit using one /3 cable, sharing the neutral with the poles correctly phased.  This goes to a 2-pole breaker or two singles with listed handle-ties. The approved handle-ties largely force you to phase the circuit correctly.  It is correct when there is 240V measured across the two hots.

Because of that, MWBCs can also support 240V mixed right in on the circuit.  Or for that matter, right on the receptacle!  Look closely at the hot pin on the lower outlet.  That's NEMA 6-20 (240V)!  When you mix 120V and 240V on a MWBC, the breaker must be "common trip".

[image]

*The black/L1 side has a breakaway tab that is not broken.  The Neutral/L2 side doesn't even have a tab - you would never connect the screws on that side!*

Answer (score 2):

Split receptacles are essentially separate devices. The fact that they're supplied by tandem breakers (which are also effectively independent devices) is immaterial. I assume that the panel is *rated* for such breakers in the first place.

As long as you don't have a multi-wire branch circuit, where you're sharing neutral, it's all good. If you *do*, there may be other considerations.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure your panel is designed to handle tandem style breakers.
This website has great information on how to make sure:

"Check the Model Name of Your Circuit Breaker
The first thing to check is the name of your panelboard. You’ll find your answer in the first four-digit number.

For example, a G3040BL1200 tells you that it offers 30 spaces but can support 40 total circuits. The only way it could do this is if it allows for tandem circuit breakers.

On the other hand, if your panel is a G3030BL1150, you know that it has 30 spaces but only allows for 30 circuits. If you installed even one tandem breaker, you’d exceed that amount, so this panel does not allow for them.

Check the Panel board’s Diagram
If you don’t know the model name of your panel board, you can always check its diagram. This will show you not just if tandem breakers are allowed but, if so, where they can be installed.

Those slots that only allow full-sized breakers will be empty. Those that allow for tandem breakers will feature a single line inside the slot.

Another way of showing this will be a diagram that has one single line, representing the entire panel, with individual lines sprouting off it, representing the breakers. Any line that turns into two (these lines usually have a marked “hump” to them) shows you where tandem breakers are allowed, if at all.

Many diagrams offer some kind of key, so be sure to check for that before trying to interpret it. For example, some panel board diagrams will show lines in each and every empty slot, though that actually represents only full-sized breakers."

[https://www.circuitbreakerwholesale.com/blogs/circuit-breakers/tandem-breakers-what-you-need-to-know#:~:text=Fortunately%2C%20despite%20that%20moniker%2C%20tandem,them%20in%20the%20correct%20locations](https://www.circuitbreakerwholesale.com/blogs/circuit-breakers/tandem-breakers-what-you-need-to-know#:%7E:text=Fortunately%2C%20despite%20that%20moniker%2C%20tandem,them%20in%20the%20correct%20locations).

If not, another option would be to use 4 of the dedicated round style 20A receptacles. This way there would be no confusion whether 1/2 of the receptacle was still live if one of the non-tandem style breakers tripped.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.